# The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql160DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms, database-migration, azure-sql-managed-instance

I'm trying to deploy to Azure SQL Database a dacpac generated by a Visual Studio build output file. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server  Management Studio 18 and SQL Sever 2022.

This is the error I get.

> Could not deploy package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql160DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

The target platform of the SQL Project is SQL Server 2022 or Azure SQL Managed Instanced.

I couldn't find any solution.

I tried changing different compatibility levels, looked at the Microsoft docs and read a lot of stack overflow questions similar to this one.

Comment: As an FYI, SSMS 18 doesn't fully support SQL Server 2022; you really should be using the latest version of SSMS. Also, if you are using SQL Server 2022, why have you tagged Azure SQL Database? That's a different product.

Comment: WEll, now that you've removed that tag, I suggest you update your SSMS, and try again with a version that *supports* the version of SQL Serve royu are using.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! I'm updating my SSMS

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs due to the use of an older version of `ssms`. As Thom suggests, updating the `ssms` version resolves the issue as you can see below:

After updating the `ssms` version, follow these steps to deploy a `dacpac` file generated by Visual Studio to Azure SQL Database:

- Create a database and a table in `Visual Studio`
  [image]
- After creating the table build your project or click `ctrl + shift + B` to create a `dacpac` file.
  [image]
- I have updated `ssms` to version 19.2 and connects it to Azure SQL Server and navigate to the **Object Explorer** window. Right-click on **Databases** and select `Deploy Data-tier Application`.
- Click `Select package` and navigate to the location where your DACPAC file is stored.
- Click on `Next` to select the target database where you want to deploy the DACPAC.
- Then the `dacpac` file will be successfully deployed to the Azure SQL Server as shown below.
  [image][image]

Comment: Thanks for your step by step. The problem I have now is that some dbs contain pre and post-deployment referencing another db and because Azure takes all the dbs in the instances as isolated dbs, those references fail :/